row and column offset within the interleaved matrix for turbo encoder
how can I obtain the row and column offset within the interleaved matrix for start address of the rate matching in turbo encoder? These two offsets are required by xilinx  IP core. are there any matlab or C codes? In other words these parameters specify the start address of the output for the rate matcher relative to sub-block interleaver matrix.
Thanks in advance
